# Does the transformation $Ax$ change the orientation of the vector $x$?

Tags: matrices, geometry, vectors

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^N, x\neq 0$ be a vector and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be a square matrix. It is true that the orientation of $Ax$ does not change with respect to the oroientation of $x$?

Could anyone please help me to understand why (or not)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In most cases $x$ and $Ax$ will not be parallell. In fact, if $x \neq 0$ and $Ax = \lambda x$ for some real $\lambda$, $x$ is called an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. You should check some simple cases to see that the transformation $x \mapsto Ax$ in most cases changes the direction of $x$. The mapping may actually very well be a rotation!

Comment: What do you mean by 'orientation' here?

Answer (score 1):

The resulting vector of the multiplication $Ax$, will only have the same orientation of $x$ (angle relative to the base $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1& 0 \\0 &1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$) if $Ax=\lambda x$, where $\lambda$ is a constant scalar, also know as *eigenvalue*.
So, both will have the same orientation, if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with that $\lambda$.